# Get youtube video feed by tags with space in tags

Tags: php, url, youtube-api

To get the feed of a **certain uploader with a certain tag** I use the following api url:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UPLOADER/uploads/-/TAG
```

if I wanted to search i.e. for the feed with tags `foo` and `bar`, I would use the following:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UPLOADER/uploads/-/foo/bar
```

BUT since youtube lets you specify **tags with space**, i.e. `"foo bar"`, I want to search exactly for this tag. So when I use the first URL in combination with urlencode in PHP it won't return anything.

In the browser, the URL will change to .`../uploads/-/foo%20bar`, but also no results.

When I use `uploads/-/foo/bar`, the problem is that it returns videos having the tags `'foo'` **and** `'bar'` (wrong), or only `'foo bar'` (right).

I also tried to replace the space with `/`, `+`, and `-`. Using the **keywords.cat scheme** in the URL will also return the same results.

Is there anything I missed, or is it generally not possible?

Comment: try foo+bar. Also, echo `urlencode('foo bar')` [will return spaces as +](http://codepad.org/qgbHy6dp) so I'm not sure what you are doing when you say you [urlencode in PHP](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: I've edited my question, the + sign also does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems there is a bug in the youtube api which is not fixed yet. see http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/dc195bd6ad6a1fa4/2d9cf0e15ce7de50

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned there is a [YouTube bug](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/dc195bd6ad6a1fa4/2d9cf0e15ce7de50), but you can use %2B (+) instead of a space to work around it.

So using your example:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UPLOADER/uploads/-/foo%2Bbar

I would have added this as a comment, but I lack the rep.

Comment: thanks! I will try it out tomorrow and let you know if it works in my case.

Comment: nope, does the same thing as all the other "solutions". Gives back videos, that are tagged "foo", "bar", and "foo bar", not ONLY "foo bar".

Answer (score 0):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UPLOADER/uploads/-/{http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fkeywords.cat}foo+bar

Try it with the keywords.cat specified before your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and was able to get it to work by using the
`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=` format.
i.e.
[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=+Team%20Fortress%202](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%20Team%20Fortress%202)
And you can check this by changing the `+` to a `-`:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=-Team%20Fortress%202

The downside to this is that the `q` parameter will query **all** metadata of the video, so adjust accordingly.

hth
Greg

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but since the client is responsible for the content, I can't guarantee that the metadata is adjusted accordingly. So the only way to get exactly the right tags is to read all and check afterwards in php, if the tag is really "foo bar" and not "foo" and "bar".